# Magento 2 Get value at website level

Tags: magento2

Im trying to create a custom module that handles values by store view level.

Anyway if the user does not select anything i want to get the default scope value at website level, im doing this in a multistore setup.

This is what i have already:

```
$data = $this->scopeConfig->getValue("payment/get_section/$section/$field");
```

Im getting the field with this set up at store view level because i think this is the default scope.

I have already tried by adding:  `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE` but im still getting the same value as before, the store view value, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you have used the right syntax. Make sure you use it with `\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE` and also make sure you add value after selecting specific website.

The reference image is shared below.

[image: Selection of store or website]

Let me know if this helps u.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, looking at the db, there is only store scope, i dont see any value with website scope, is this correct? so i have sent the store id and i got the value updated...but i need to know the default website id, is this the correct code snipped?
$websiteID = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId(); im always getting 1.

Comment: yes this is how you get the id.
`1` means, you are getting default website id. make sure you are on other website for which you are looking value for